# Dataframe: Obtain year of birth based on a set of rules

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in which I have to obtain the year of birth of soccer players based on the information I have: category and competition in which they participate.

First of all, I'm going to explain the logic of the categories and competitions. I have this dataframe in which you can see Age, Category and the rest of the columns are seasons. The result in the rows are the birth years of the players corresponding to each category:

```
Age Category 2023 2022 2021 2020 2019 2018 2017
19  A3       2004 2003 2002 2001 2000 1999 1998
18  A2       2005 2004 2003 2002 2001 2000 1999
17  A1       2006 2005 2004 2003 2002 2001 2000
16  B2       2007 2006 2005 2004 2003 2002 2001
15  B1       2008 2007 2006 2005 2004 2003 2002
14  C2       2009 2008 2007 2006 2005 2004 2003
13  C1       2010 2009 2008 2007 2006 2005 2004
12  D2       2011 2010 2009 2008 2007 2006 2005
11  D1       2012 2011 2010 2009 2008 2007 2006
```

In the last season (2023) the player competing in A3 category, therefore, is born in 2004. Thus, a player who in the 2020 season was D2 means that he was 12 years old and was therefore born in 2008.

Having explained this logic, I show the information that I have in my dataframe and with which I have to try to obtain the year of birth. I have these columns:

- Player: Player's name
- Season: Year (2023, 2022, etc..)
- Category: And here is one of the complications, since I don't have A1, B2, etc but A, B, C or D.

My goal is to create a function that ends up understanding the progression during the seasons by understanding the rules of the competitions and this progression:

- A player cannot play more than 2 seasons in category D: the following season he will be C.
- The same happens in category C: 2 seasons maximum and from there he will move to category B.
- The same happens with category B: 2 seasons maximum and then he moves to category A.
- Category A is the only category where you can stay for 3 seasons.

Now I show an example of a dataframe that I can find and from which I have to obtain with that data the year of birth in a new column. Logically, the year of birth has to be the same for each player: Andrew is still the same person in 2023 as in 2021, 2020, etc. Here is the dataframe and I add the column 'Year Birth' with the result I wish to obtain:

```
Player  Category    Season  Year Birth
Charly  A           2023    2006
Andrew  A           2023    2005
Louis   A           2023    2004
Peter   B           2023    2007
Charly  B           2022    2006
Andrew  A           2022    2005
Louis   A           2022    2004
Louis   A           2021    2004
Andrew  B           2021    2005
Charly  B           2021    2006
Peter   B           2022    2007
Juan    A           2022    2003
Juan    A           2021    2003
Juan    A           2020    2003
Michael C           2023    2011
Michael D           2022    2011
```

I may come across cases where information is missing. For example, a player who has only one row and has for example in the 2023 season the B category. Then I would have to put in Year Birth a result like "2007 or 2008". But it will be exceptional cases... Most likely, all players will have a history of seasons and categories that allow us to see their progression.

This is the code I'm trying with but the result is a disaster. I know I'm not doing the logic of ifs and elifs properly but I don't know how to improve and to include in the function all the variants I would like:

```
data = {
    'Player': ['Charly', 'Andrew', 'Louis', 'Peter', 'Charly', 'Andrew', 'Louis', 'Louis', 'Andrew', 'Charly',
               'Peter', 'Juan', 'Juan', 'Juan', 'Michael', 'Michael'],
    'Category': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'D'],
    'Season': [2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2021, 2020, 2023, 2022],

}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def year_birth(player, df):
    seasons_a = df[(df['Player'] == player) & (df['Category'] == 'A')]['Season']
    seasons_b = df[(df['Player'] == player) & (df['Category'] == 'B')]['Season']
    seasons_c = df[(df['Player'] == player) & (df['Category'] == 'C')]['Season']
    seasons_d = df[(df['Player'] == player) & (df['Category'] == 'D')]['Season']
    
    if len(seasons_a) >= 3:
        return 2003
    elif len(seasons_a) == 2:
        if len(seasons_b) >= 1:
            return 2004
        else:
            return 2005
    elif len(seasons_a) == 1:
        if len(seasons_b) >= 2:
            return 2005
        else:
            return 2006
    elif len(seasons_b) >= 2:
        return 2006
    elif len(seasons_b) == 1:
        return 2007
    elif len(seasons_c) >= 2:
        return 2008
    elif len(seasons_d) == 1:
        return 2009
    else:
        return None

df['Year Birth'] = df.apply(lambda row: year_birth(row['Player'], df), axis=1)

df
```

I don't know if it's a matter of conditions I'm applying or how I could improve the code to show what I need. Any help and suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be easier to just re-assign the category index and then lookup the value in your table

```
    'Player': ['Charly', 'Andrew', 'Louis', 'Peter', 'Charly', 'Andrew', 'Louis', 'Louis', 'Andrew', 'Charly',
               'Peter', 'Juan', 'Juan', 'Juan', 'Michael', 'Michael'],
    'Category': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'D'],
    'Season': [2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2021, 2020, 2023, 2022],
    'Year Birth': [2006, 2005, 2004, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2011, 2011]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# define a column where we will compute the index. Set to 1 to start
df['CategoryIndex'] = 1
# sort values
df = df.sort_values(['Player', 'Season'], ascending=True).reset_index(drop=True)
# calculate the cumulated sum for the CategoryIndex for each Player/Category, and join it to the original dataframe
df = df[['Player','Category','Season','Year Birth']] \
    .join(df[['Player', 'Category', 'CategoryIndex']].groupby(['Player', 'Category']).cumsum())
# combine the Category with the computed CategoryIndex
df['Category'] = df['Category'] + df['CategoryIndex'].astype(str)
```

and we have:

```
    Player  Category    Season  Year Birth  CategoryIndex
0   Andrew  B1  2021    2005    1
1   Andrew  A1  2022    2005    1
2   Andrew  A2  2023    2005    2
3   Charly  B1  2021    2006    1
4   Charly  B2  2022    2006    2
5   Charly  A1  2023    2006    1
6   Juan    A1  2020    2003    1
7   Juan    A2  2021    2003    2
8   Juan    A3  2022    2003    3
9   Louis   A1  2021    2004    1
10  Louis   A2  2022    2004    2
11  Louis   A3  2023    2004    3
12  Michael D1  2022    2011    1
13  Michael C1  2023    2011    1
14  Peter   B1  2022    2007    1
15  Peter   B2  2023    2007    2
```

Now, it's a lookup in your table to find the year of birth from the Category and Season

```
def yob_lookup(row):
    y = row['Season']
    x = row['Category']
    return yob_table.loc[x,y]

df['Year of Birth'] = df.apply(yob_lookup, axis=1)
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a big mistake with my code. In my original df there is no 'Year Birth' column. It's precisely that column that I have to extract from the df data from the Category and Season. I edited the code with the proper df I have.

Also I tried the def yob_lookup and I receive: KeyError: 2021